# Extending ismember to cells

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cells

I have searched the forum and have not found enough info to help me solve this problem.

Consider the set (cell of vectors)

```
A = {[1],[1 2],[2],[1 2 3],[1 2 3 4],[1 3]}
```

I want to construct a matrix B that looks like

```
B = [1 1 0 1 1 1
     0 1 0 1 1 0
     0 1 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

The matrix B specifies membership of vectors with respect to each other. That is, the first row looks at the first element in A, [1], and checks if it is a member of the other vectors, placing a 1 if it is a member and a 0 otherwise.

I can do this using two for loops: one over the elements of A, and another nested, for each element of A, that checks membership with respect to every other member of A.

I want to avoid using for loops. Is there a vectorized solution for obtaining B from A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cell arrays it's hard to avoid loops, or their cousin [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). This is how I would do it:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(A)); % indices of all possible pairs
result = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), A(ii), A(jj)); % see if all elements in the 
    % first are present in the second
```

Comment: Nice solution. You mentioned cellfun is a cousin of a loop -- does it basically just loop over all elements of the cell?

Comment: @jonem Yes, it takes each cell from the input/s  and applies the specified function to it/them. Performance-wise it's similar to a loop. Vectorization is usually not possible for cells :-(

Answer (score 2):

Well you asked for it, so here's an almost* vectorized solution using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) -

```
lens = cellfun('length',A) 
vals = [A{:}]

mask = bsxfun(@ge,lens,[1:max(vals)]')
a = nan(size(mask))
a(mask) = vals
matches =  bsxfun(@eq,a,permute(a,[3,4,1,2]));
out = bsxfun(@eq,squeeze(sum(any(matches,3),1)),lens(:))
```

*: Almost because of the use of `cellfun` at the start with `cellfun('length',A)`, but since its just getting the length of the cells there, so computationally would be negligible  .

Also, please note that this approach would use a lot of memory resources, so might not be beneficial, but just respecting the requirements of a vectorized solution as much as possible!